# Animate Scroll based on Hash Change

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, hashchange

I'm currently working on a site which uses the javascript code below to animate over to the target element inside an href. How would I go about getting the code to animate when the back/forward buttons are clicked based on it's history.

```
/* ------  Smooth Scroll ----- */

$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    $('a[href*=#]').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent the "normal" behaviour which would be a "hard" jump

        var target = $(this).attr("href"); //Get the target

        // perform animated scrolling by getting top-position of target-element and set it as scroll target
        $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(target).offset().top}, 2000, function()
        {
            location.hash = target;  //attach the hash (#jumptarget) to the pageurl
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Could you include your HTML so that we can see how it is working now?

Comment: Ben Alman did the hard work for you! http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for the hash change. There are many ways to do this. You can poll for hash change or use HTML5's history api with `onhashchange` method to listen for changes. The easiest way to do this is probably using some kind of library that already takes care of both. I recommend [jquery](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) plugin if you are using jquery. If you are using angular js or other stuff then look for those plugins.

You would do something like

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){
  // Do the animation here
})
```

You would no longer need to animate on `a` click.

Comment: I put the following inside the hashchange function using the jquery hashchange plugin but can't get it to animate.
`$('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(target).offset().top}, 2000, function() { location.hash = target; });`

Comment: this is the event, not "hashchange" `$(window).on('hashchange',function(){`